# Conflict between jCarousel and jQZoom jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jqzoom

I try putting a jCarousel and jQZoom plugin and run both after dom and they both don't work. When I try only jCarousel it works, and vice versa. How can I run both plugins well after dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably they both create same class and element names, check the html output of both then try to change them by editing their special js files.

Comment: so far they have no similar elements

Comment: pls check spme binding unbinding functions in their js files also. They may override their code.